# Simulate a drifted brownian motion in heston model

Tags: brownian-motion, finance, simulation, python, programming

I am trying to simulate the instanteneous volatility of a Heston process.

My equations are the following :

**wealth process:**
$$dX_t = r_t X_t + \theta \sqrt {V_t} u_t\, dt + u_t \,dW_{1t}$$

**Volatility:**
$$dV_t = (\kappa \phi - \lambda V_t) \,dt + \sigma \sqrt {V_t} \, dB_t $$

With, I start my simulations with a 2D brownian motion : $(W_1, W_2)$ and another "corrolated" Brownian motion $B_t = \rho \, d \widetilde{W}_{1t} + \sqrt{1- \rho^2} \, dW_{2t} $

My problem lies in the $d \widetilde{W}_{1t}$. Its definition is :

$$ \widetilde{W}_{1t} = W_{1t} + 2 \theta \int_0^t \sqrt {V_s} \, ds. $$

So I know how to simulate the wealth process, it s a classical "flow".

The volatility follows the same pattern, iff the brownian motion $dB_t$ is a classical one. Here there is a drift movement which makes the whole simulation cyclic. I have no idea how to deal with it.

1. Is it possible to simulate that ? Is my problem markovian ?
2. How would one deal with that problem. I simply need a solution for $\tilde{W}_{1t} $, I'll deal with the rest.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ d\widetilde{W}_{1t} = d W_{1t} + 2 \theta \sqrt {V_s} dt $$
Then one can replace 
$$ dB_t = \rho d  W_{1t} + 2 \theta \sqrt {V_s} dt + \sqrt{1- \rho^2} dW_{2t} $$